# How does backreferencing in the search pattern work in GNU Sed?

Tags: sed, backreference, gnu-sed

Given that

```bash
echo -e 'one.onetwo' | sed -n 's/\(.*\)\.\1/x/p'
```

prints `xtwo`, why does the following print `onextwo`?

```bash
echo -e 'one.two' | sed -n 's/\(.*\)\.\1/x/p'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo -e 'one.two' | sed -n 's/\(.*\)\.\1/x/p'
```

The're only one place where `\.` can match: the dot between `one` and `two`. As there's no non-empty substring repeating before and after the dot, the `.*` matches the empty one. Then, the empty substring, the dot, and the repeated empty substring are replaced by `x`.

```
one ∅ . ∅ two
one ----- two
one   x   two
```

Comment: Compare the above with `echo -e 'one.two' | sed -En 's/(.+)\.\1/x/p'` and notice the `+`.